# Long underbrace with exponent following

Tags: math-mode

The following code results in the following output.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
${\underbrace{\left(a^k\right)}_{\text{very long text}}}^{s}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the exponent `s` close to the bracket?

Comment: use `mathtools` and wrap the `\text{...}` in `\mathclap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` to make the exponent zero width:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\underbrace{(a^k)^{\mathrlap{s}}}_{\text{very long text}}$

\end{document}
```

Avoid `\left(` and `\right)` in that context. If you've read that you should always use them, then forget it: it's not true. If your editor adds them automatically, change this setting as soon as possible.

[image]

As *hawk eye* barbara beeton remarks, there is a small asymmetry, which may or may not be desirable.

In order to get perfect symmetry in the underbrace, we need to remove the additional space that TeX inserts when a sub/superscript is added. I'll show both version one above the other, so you can decide what'e better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\underbrace{(a^k)^{\mathrlap{s}}\kern-\scriptspace}_{\text{very long text}}$

$\underbrace{(a^k)^{\mathrlap{s}}}_{\text{very long text}}$

\end{document}
```

The `\scriptspace` parameter is 0.5pt, which is small but noticeable indeed.

[image]

Comment: it's probably an illusion, but the brace appears to be positioned just a little to the right, not quite centered.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You always surprise me. ;-) There's `\scriptspace`, of course!